# How to compare two age one age is given and other age is calculated age in ms sql server2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to compare two age one age is given and other age is calculated age in ms sql server2008

```
select FNAME,LNAME, cast(datediff(DAY,DOB, '03-OCT-2015') /
(365.23076923074) as int) as 'calcAge' from students1 order by Age asc
```

Ans i get fname ,lname and calcAge

this is the age given in the table

```
 insert into students values(1, 'Jon', 'Smith', 30, '10-FEB-2000');
 insert into students values(2, 'Jane', 'Smith', 20, '12-FEB-1993');
 insert into students values(3, 'Joan', 'Smith', 75, '16-OCT-1938');
 insert into students values(4, 'Joanne', 'Smith', 18, '20-JUN-1995');
```

this calcage needs to be compared with the age in students table and if that age matches it should return true else no

```
select AGE,FNAME,LNAME,cast(datediff(DAY,DOB, '03-OCT-2015') /
(365.23076923074)  as int) as 'cal' from students1 (case when (AGE = AGE as 'cal')   THEN  '1'  ELSE  '0'  END)
```

its returning error .please correct me

Comment: Why did you tag this with mysql if you are using sql server?

Answer (score 0):

```
 select FNAME
       ,LNAME
       ,Age
       , cast(datediff(DAY,DOB, '03-OCT-2015') /(365.23076923074) as int) as 'calcAge' 
       , CASE WHEN cast(datediff(DAY,DOB, '03-OCT-2015') /(365.23076923074) as int) 
                   = Age 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AgeCompare     
from students1 
order by Age asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would compare a given age to a calculated age in T-SQL

```
select case
            when
                (case 
                    when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                        then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
                    else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
                end) = 19
                then 'Same age'
            else 'Not same age'
        end as AgeCompare
go
```